# Are there computer requirements other than basic C++ for being accepted to a graduate program in Non-Linear Dynamics?

Tags: soft-question, career-development

Ladies and Gentlemen

I am currently studying applied mathematics and statistics. I am more than just a little bit interested in studying non-linear dynamics at a graduate level.

I was wondering if, other than an intro to C++ programming, there were any other general computer requirements to being admitted into a non-linear dynamics graduate program?

I am trying to figure this stuff out now, instead of applying to graduate programs and being denied because I only have one computer class under my belt.

I appreciate any and all responses!

Answer (score 2):

Requirements for graduate programs are generally listed in a university's catalogue or department web site.  I don't know which university you're talking about, and couldn't which possibly speak for them in any case.  But in general,
I would say that specific computer programming abilities would be among the least important requirements for a graduate mathematics program.  It's nice if you have some such qualifications, but if not you could pick up what you need when you need it.  More important qualifications would be courses in, e.g., analysis and differential equations.